# Transactions not processed (Ethereum Network in Azure)

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, web3js, microsoft-azure, blockchain-as-a-service

I have the following setup:

- In Azure I have virtual network and within the virtual network a full node (TX0) and a mining node (MN0). They have each other added as static peers.
- The virtual network has a firewall with the following rules: Inbound port 30303 TCP & UDP and 8545 TCP, outbound 30303 TCP & UDP
- Only TX0 has a public IP address, MN0 has only a private IP address
- Everything works fine within the boundaries of the virtual network.
- I started a full node (TX1) running locally on my laptop. As static peer I added TX0 (MN0 is not possible as it only has a private IP)
- TX1 is part of the network and also syncs the blocks but...

And here is the problem:

- The account created on TX1 can receive ether when send from another account within the virtual network, but when I issue a transaction on TX1 it is not processed (a transaction hash is created but nothing happens then and also no receipt is available at any time as well as the balance of the account send from stays the same) (the account to send from is unlocked)
- Command

> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: '0x...', value:
>   web3.toWei(1, "ether")})

What is the problem?

Comment: Is one of the nodes mining in the network? Only miners can process transactions.

Comment: Yes. And it seems as if it is only possible to send transactions from accounts on the miner node to accounts on other nodes. If I try to send a transaction from TX0 or TX1 they are just not processed. And I don't know why. Just sending Ether shouldn't be a problem usually...

Comment: And it has nothing to do with the private / public IP topic as I added public IPs to all nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a second miner and now it works. Bug or is this on purpose?